# python xarray tick label size issue

Tags: python, python-xarray, cartopy

I am new for xarray and cartopy. I want to ask how can I increase/decrease labelsize on x-/y- ticks.
Following is my code.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8)) 
ax  = plt.axes(projection =ccrs.PlateCarree())   
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND,facecolor='wheat') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN) 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES, linestyle='-',lw=1.0,edgecolor='white') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-',lw=2.5,edgecolor='white') 
gp = ds.isel(time=0).gpm.plot.pcolormesh('lon','lat',ax=ax,
             infer_intervals=True,vmin=0,vmax=1600,cmap='jet',extend='both') 
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m',color='white') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS) 
gl = ax.gridlines(color='gray',alpha=0.6,draw_labels=True) 
gl.xlabels_top, gl.ylabels_right = False, False 
ax.yaxis.tick_right() 
ax.set_ylim([18,32]) 
ax.set_xlim([-100,-77])  
ax.set_title('GPM Accumulated Rain (12Z Aug24 - 12Z Aug31)', fontsize=16) 
ax.set_aspect('equal') 
ax.tick_params('both',labelsize=30) 
plt.show()
```

I have added tick_params to set up the labelsize, but the size of the font is still in the default size. Meanwhile, could anyone tell me how to move colorbar label to colorbar title?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fontsize of the tick labels can be set by passing a style dictionary to the Gridliner in a similar way you have toggled the top and right labels:

```
gl.xlabel_style = {fontsize: 30}
gl.ylabel_style = {fontsize: 40}
```

This results in the your code looking like:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8)) 
ax  = plt.axes(projection =ccrs.PlateCarree())   
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND,facecolor='wheat') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN) 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES, linestyle='-',lw=1.0,edgecolor='white') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-',lw=2.5,edgecolor='white') 
gp = ds.isel(time=0).gpm.plot.pcolormesh('lon','lat',ax=ax,
             infer_intervals=True,vmin=0,vmax=1600,cmap='jet',extend='both') 
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m',color='white') 
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS) 
gl = ax.gridlines(color='gray',alpha=0.6,draw_labels=True) 
gl.xlabels_top, gl.ylabels_right = False, False
gl.xlabel_style, gl.ylabel_style = {'fontsize': 30}, {'fontsize': 40}
ax.yaxis.tick_right() 
ax.set_ylim([18,32]) 
ax.set_xlim([-100,-77])  
ax.set_title('GPM Accumulated Rain (12Z Aug24 - 12Z Aug31)', fontsize=16) 
ax.set_aspect('equal') 
plt.show()
```

Which should produce a plot looking like this (minus the data):
[image: Plot with gridline labels of differing font size]

In reality the GeoAxis in Cartopy *should* handle `ax.tick_params('both', labelsize=30)`, but it seems that this is not passed down when the labels are generated. Feel free to raise an issue on the [Cartopy GitHub repository](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues) where the community of developers can fix it. Or have a go at fixing it yourself by submitting a pull request!

Comment: Thanks, I tried plt.rc and plt.rcParams and they didn't work, too.