# How to use matplotlib.pyplot.contourf to plot a density array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-xarray, matplotlib-basemap

I have an xarray Dataset called dens that I would like to plot.

This is the Dataset:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 641, lat: 30, lon: 30)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-07-01T12:00:00 ... 2013-08-02T12:00:00
  * lon      (lon) float64 32.73 32.83 32.94 33.05 ... 35.53 35.64 35.75 35.85
  * lat      (lat) float64 31.08 31.27 31.47 31.66 ... 36.06 36.25 36.44 36.63
Data variables:
    density  (time, lat, lon) float64 2e+03 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I am using the command

```
plt.contourf(dens.density.values[-1,:,:]);
```

to plot it and it's working, but since I would like to have the coastline also drawn on the plot, I am also trying to use

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=data['lon'].min(), llcrnrlat=data['lat'].min(),
                urcrnrlon=data['lon'].max(), urcrnrlat=data['lat'].max(), resolution='i', suppress_ticks=1)
m.drawcoastlines();
m.fillcontinents(color='gray',lake_color='gray');
```

But when I run all of the commands, and then run `plt.show()` ,the contour plot disappears, and all that it shows me is the coastline.

How could I fix this to get a contour plot + the coastline plot in the same figure?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but i'm pretty new to python

Thank you for any help,

Yotam

**EDIT:** I only just now realized that I am trying to combine two different "toolkits", and that there is a possibility to do all of this using only the basemap toolkit, but just trying to write

```
m.contourf(dens.density.values[-1,:,:]);
```

gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 m.contourf(dens.density.values[-1,:,:])

TypeError: Basemap.contourf() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'data'
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:** I keep discovering more things as I go along, after reading the documentation of Basemap, I realized that the syntax of the command should be something like this

`m.contourf(dens.lon.values,dens.lat.values,dens.density.values[-1,:,:]);`

but now I get this error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I'm guessing this is because of my density array, which is 2D, but how do I extract from it just the density values? I'm using the [-1] in the time dimension because I only actually need the last timestep

Again, thanks in advance,
Yotam

**LAST EDIT**

This is the final plot, how can I make the land around to be grey instead of purple? Also, is there a way to depict a larger geographical area, just a bit larger, without messing with the data?

[image]

This is the new figure with my actual data

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share the dataset that you are using? Then I could try it too.

Comment: Can you add somepart of the data so I can use it to try a solution?

Comment: @molinav I figured out thanks to the answer below, but now I have a new question, how would I be able to change the colorbar? For example to be able to control the values of where the colors change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plotting with basemap and xarray is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968629/plotting-lat-lon-gridlines-using-matplotlib-basemap-and-xarray).

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=data['lon'].min(), llcrnrlat=data['lat'].min(),
            urcrnrlon=data['lon'].max(), urcrnrlat=data['lat'].max(), 
  resolution='i', suppress_ticks=1)
m.drawcoastlines();
m.fillcontinents(color='gray',lake_color='gray')
dens.density[-1,:,:].plot.contourf()
plt.show()
```

The above code should work.
I use cartopy for features like coastlines and borders. Below is the working code snippet for you to try with your dataset.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf

ds = xr.open_dataset('filename.nc')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=crs)
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=crs, draw_labels=True,
                linewidth=0.01, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='-.')

ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE.with_scale("50m"), lw=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS.with_scale("50m"), lw=0.3)

ds.density[-1,:,:].plot.contourf()
plt.show()
```

## For the last edit

To set all the purple(zeros) to white you can use the following cmap.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white', *plt.cm.Blues(np.arange(255))])
ds.density[-1,:,:].plot.contourf(cmap=cm)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I just tried running the first lines of code and it worked! I will also try using the code you wrote using cartopy, to see if it also works.

Comment: I also tried your cartopy code, it also works really well, even looks better than the basemap figure. Just a couple of questions that apply to both approaches.The figure returns the land as purple, since purple is the colour that depicts values of 0 on my density scale, could this be changed to be grey? Also, is there any way of expanding the geographical area that is portrayed? I will try to find a way to post the figure here so you can see what it looks like. Thank you again for your help and patience

Comment: I will edit the original question and post the plot there

Comment: I have one more final question, and this one is relevant whether I use either the Basemap or the cartopy code. How can I change the default colorbar? I would like to split it into more color divisions?

Comment: Could you please repeat the code, it doesn't seem to work, maybe you accidentally pressed a typo?

Comment: Did you try the code I put in the answer?

Comment: I just saw your edit, thank you! It works perfectly, but I was also curious to if there is a way to change the values of where the colors change? Because my actual dataset includes much higher values, and it groups all values 0 to 20 as the minimum contour. I will add the mentioned figure in my question above

Comment: You can use vmax, vmin keywords to limit the values in the contourf function.